# Build and Run does not work with Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, xcode7

I have installed the latest version of Unity (5.2.2f1 personal) and the Build and Run option for an iOS build does not work with Xcode 7.1.

The Build is successful, but it warns me that the `latest version of Xcode is not in Unity's compatibility list`. In the "What's new" area for the latest version of Unity, it lists that this bug has been fixed ([see here](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.2.2)).

There have been a few comments that you should downgrade to Xcode 6.4, but this is no good if you want to run on mobile operating systems > iOS 9.

On the Unity Issue tracker the status of this bug is fixed ([see here](http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-build-and-run-doesnt-work-with-xcode-7-and-7-dot-1)). Does anybody know of a workaround for this?